# Yii2 search model

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

On my website, when I search Alex Lau, I will show the result Alex Lau. The problem is how can I modify the code so when I search Lau Alex maybe, It will still show Alex Lau result. Right now it didn't.

```
$query->orFilterWhere(['like', 'fullname', $this->globalSearch])
```

Here is the code in my search model.

Please help me with this.

Thank you!

Comment: What does globalSearch variable contain?

Comment: Do you need a feature like full-text search?

Comment: Alex Lau is a different string from Lau Alex so i think you have to divide in 2 different string and search with 2 where condition.

Comment: You can separate words and loop through each word and prepare a query for it. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37229355/mysql-search-for-multiple-keywords-in-same-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach according to the MYSQL query using `CONCAT()`like below

```
if( $this->fullname!== null && $this->fullname !== '' ){
    $searchTerms = explode(" ", $this->fullname);
    if( sizeof($searchTerms) > 1 ){
        $conditions[]='OR';
        foreach( $searchTerms as $term ){
            $conditions[] = ['like', 'fullname', new \yii\db\Expression('CONCAT(CONCAT("%","' . $term . '"),"%")')];
        }
        $query->orFilterWhere($conditions);
    } else{
        $query->orFilterWhere(
                ['like', 'fullname', new \yii\db\Expression('CONCAT(CONCAT("%","' . $searchTerms[0] . '"),"%")')]
        );
    }

}
```

*NOTE: This works correctly if you are searching the name in the format `first last` or `first middle last`, means you can search `Alex Lau John` or `John Alex Lau` `Lau John Alex`*

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$words = explode(' ',$this->globalSearch);

if (count($words) > 1) {
    foreach ($words as $word) {
        $query->orFilterWhere(['like', 'fullname', $word]);
    }
} else {
    $query->orFilterWhere(['like', 'fullname', $this->globalSearch]);
}
```

**Note:** You need to make sure about white spaces

Comment: Thank you, I am testing this now.